# Can a MySQL stored procedure return a stream of rows without storing them in a temp table?

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a stored procedure that will perform a SELECT, loop through it with a cursor, do some mildly complicated processing, and then return some of the rows in a modified form.

One way to do this is to create a temporary table, insert the results of the processing there, and then finish the procedure with a `select * from temp_table;`

I'm wondering if I can skip that part and just stream the computed rows directly to the client, without involving the overhead of temporary storage.

Comment: Ummm...yes...what language are you accessing mysql from?

Comment: @Forbs - PHP/mysqli, although I was hoping that the answer would be client(language)-agnostic.

Comment: You could, it would take a multi layered select...just pretty complicated

Comment: Yes. It would be exactly like a select statement. Make sure all of the columns have a name, then call those names in your result sets.

Comment: Hmm, returning every single row as a new result set? Well, yes, that would work, but wouldn't there be even more overhead this way? I was really trying to do this for performance.

Comment: No, you return the result row in 1 select, perform some operations, then use it in another select...it's multilayered as I said.

Comment: I... don't think I understand then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every unbounded `SELECT` within a stored procedure writes a separate result-set to the wire.  The only way to combine them into a single result-set is to use a temporary table, and then `SELECT` from it when you're done.

Otherwise, the multiple result sets must be iterated by the client by calling [`more_results`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.more-results.php), which tells you whether more results are available.  It returns false when your procedure finishes.

The mechanism MySQL uses to actually write these multiple result sets is very lightweight, so it depends on whether this works for what you're trying to do, whether this is useful in your application.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, by Defining Output Parameters**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Jahr_Monat`(

IN  in_jahr int,
OUT out_mon_int int,
OUT out_monat VARCHAR(50),
OUT out_mon int, 
OUT out_quartal int,
OUT out_halbjahr int, 
OUT out_jahr int
)
BEGIN
    IF in_jahr IS NULL THEN
        SET in_jahr=YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()); 
    END IF;
    Select 1  `Mon_int`,'Januar'    `Monat`, 'JAN'    `MON`,1  `Quartal`,1  `Halbjahr`,in_jahr `Jahr` UNION
    Select 2  `Mon_int`,'Februar'   `Monat`, 'FEB'   `MON`,1  `Quartal`,1  `Halbjahr`,in_jahr `Jahr` UNION
    Select 3  `Mon_int`,'März'      `Monat`, 'MÄR'      `MON`,1  `Quartal`,1  `Halbjahr`,in_jahr `Jahr` UNION
    Select 4  `Mon_int`,'April'     `Monat`, 'APR'     `MON`,2  `Quartal`,1  `Halbjahr`,in_jahr `Jahr` UNION
    Select 5  `Mon_int`,'Mai'       `Monat`, 'MAI'       `MON`,2  `Quartal`,1  `Halbjahr`,in_jahr `Jahr` UNION
    Select 6  `Mon_int`,'Juni'      `Monat`, 'JUN'      `MON`,2  `Quartal`,1  `Halbjahr`,in_jahr `Jahr` UNION
    Select 7  `Mon_int`,'Juli'      `Monat`, 'JUL'      `MON`,3  `Quartal`,2  `Halbjahr`,in_jahr `Jahr` UNION
    Select 8  `Mon_int`,'August'    `Monat`, 'AUG'    `MON`,3  `Quartal`,2  `Halbjahr`,in_jahr `Jahr` UNION
    Select 9  `Mon_int`,'September' `Monat`, 'SEP' `MON`,3  `Quartal`,2  `Halbjahr`,in_jahr `Jahr` UNION
    Select 10 `Mon_int`,'Oktober'   `Monat`, 'OKT'   `MON`,4  `Quartal`,2  `Halbjahr`,in_jahr `Jahr` UNION
    Select 11 `Mon_int`,'November'  `Monat`, 'NOV'  `MON`,4  `Quartal`,2  `Halbjahr`,in_jahr `Jahr` UNION
    Select 12 `Mon_int`,'Dezembr'   `Monat`, 'DEZ'   `MON`,4  `Quartal`,2  `Halbjahr`,in_jahr `Jahr` 
    ;

END

CALL Jahr_Monat(NULL, @out_mon_int,
@out_monat,
@out_mon , 
@out_quartal ,
@out_halbjahr , 
@out_jahr )  ;

Mon_int     Monat       MON     Quartal     Halbjahr    Jahr
1           Januar      JAN     1           1           2024
2           Februar     FEB     1           1           2024
3           März        MÄR     1           1           2024
4           April       APR     2           1           2024
5           Mai         MAI     2           1           2024
6           Juni        JUN     2           1           2024
7           Juli        JUL     3           2           2024
8           August      AUG     3           2           2024
9           September   SEP     3           2           2024
10          Oktober     OKT     4           2           2024
11          November    NOV     4           2           2024
12          Dezembr     DEZ     4           2           2024
```